# I want to make a Google App Engine application; have a decent JavaSE/Swing + Javascript/(X)HTML + relational database (SQL) background

Tags: google-app-engine

Can you refer me to a good starting place for learning GAE from what I already know?  I plan to make a fairly elaborate application, and I'm not completely certain on where to start or how far I'll need to go (JavaEE?).  I'd rather hear from someone who already knows what's involved than start off by guessing and stumbling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up until now the best documentation Ive found is the official one on [code.google.com/appengine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html).
One JavaEE doc that comes in handy is the [HttpServlet Spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr154/index.html), since this is the basic class for responding to http requests on App Engine.
For file uploads there is a useful lib at [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).
Since you are not allowed to manipulate files on the server in gae, all your persistence will need some knowledge of the datastore, jdo and [datanucleus enhancer](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/orm/inheritance.html).

Additionally to that you might want to consider using a third party framework to be more productive. 
There are a lot of products for various purposes around. What kind of application will you develop?

Comment: I suppose you could say its interface works like a search engine's, but with a few more added steps for the user to handle.  It is not a search engine, though.

I should add that I'm also acquainted with using relational databases, and a lot of work with those will likely be involved in this.

Comment: The Datastore is not like a relational database in any way shape or form. I have found that my knowledge of SQL is almost completely useless.

Comment: "JDOQL is similar to SQL, but is more appropriate for object-oriented databases like the App Engine datastore" http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Introducing_Queries